# The equivalence of $Y=XX^T$ - by Schur complement and rank constraint

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, matrix-rank, linear-matrix-inequality

I am confused about the following lemma which is useful to convex optimization problem:
( From http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/599549/ )

[image]

I know the left one is by Schur complement (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement):   $$Z\succeq 0 \Longleftrightarrow Y\succeq 0, Y-XX^T\succeq 0 $$

However, the above only shows $Y\succeq XX^T$.  The rank constraint (right hand side) tells me what?

I have no idea how to use the right constraint to show the equality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use elementary operations on the right part of

$$
\text{rank}
\begin{bmatrix}
    Y       & X \\
    X^T       & I_q \\   
\end{bmatrix}
$$
to subtract it multiplied by $X^T$ from the left part. Get the following
$$
\text{rank}
\begin{bmatrix}
    Y-XX^T       & X \\
    0       & I_q \\   
\end{bmatrix}
$$

For the resulted block matrix it is [known](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1567957/140670) that 
$$q =
\text{rank}
\begin{bmatrix}
    Y-XX^T       & X \\
    0       & I_q \\   
\end{bmatrix} 
\ge 
\text{rank}(Y-XX^T)+\text{rank}(I_q)\ge \text{rank}(Y-XX^T)+q
$$

Then $\text{rank}(Y-XX^T) = 0$, and the matrix $Y-XX^T$ contains only zero eigenvalues. So $$Y-XX^T = 0.$$

**Edit**

Elementary operation on matrices do not change their ranks. So

$$
\text{rank}
\begin{bmatrix}
    Y       & X \\
    X^T       & I_q \\   
\end{bmatrix}
=\text{rank}
\begin{bmatrix}
    Y-XX^T       & X \\
    0       & I_q \\   
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Could you please detail how to obtain the second matrix? (the fourth line)

Comment: @sleevechen, essentially, it amounts to multiplication of right side of the first matrix by $X^T$ and its further subtraction from the left side.

Comment: Ok I see. Then why could you do this such that the rank is unchanged? (i.e. the first matrix and the second matrix are of the same rank)

Comment: @sleevechen, elementary operations on matrix should not change its rank

Comment: I see; I almost forget this. The last question is how do you know $q = \operatorname{rank}...$ the first equality?

Comment: @sleevechen, do you mean your second condition that you have posted in your question?

Comment: Ok. I see.  I get it. Thanks