# $\text{Rank} \begin{pmatrix} A & X \\ 0 & B \end{pmatrix} \geq \text{Rank}(A) + \text{Rank}(B)$ for any $n \times n$ matrices $A,B, X$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, matrix-rank

Question: Let $A,B$ and $X$ be $n\times n$ matrices, I need to show that

\begin{align} 
 \text{Rank} \begin{pmatrix}  A & X \\ 0 & B \end{pmatrix} \geq \text{Rank}(A) + \text{Rank}(B).
\end{align}

This is exercise 26, page 16 in the book Matrix theory by Zhang. I was trying to review linear algebra again and got stuck at this problem. Any hint would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1567957/rank-of-block-triangular-matrix-and-its-relation-to-the-rank-of-its-diagonal-blo

Comment: Thank you, I was searching for this but it never showed up on my search :(

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth By the way, can you give me some advice on how to search for the questions like above? I tried a lot of keywords but never found the exact questions I wanted

Comment: I think in this case I searched for keywords like "rank of block triangular matrix stackexchange".